# Regular expression for IN and NOT IN Operator

Tags: regex

I have filter string like

```
"(empID = 10) AND (age IN ('10', '12', '2')) OR name NOT IN ( 'eq', 'test') AND (name='Gorge')"
```

I just want to replace the `"IN ("` to `"IN ["` so my final string filter string will be like this

```
"(empID = 10) AND (age IN ['10', '12', '2']) OR name NOT IN [ 'eq', 'test'] AND (name='Gorge')"
```

Can anyone help me for what  will be my regular expression for above filter string.

Comment: What does this have to do with regular expression? If you want to parse a string with regex, then give at least give some examples a regex should match or not.

Comment: Do NOT parse MySQL with regexes, use a dedicated parser, or at least a parser with a *context-free grammar*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases you may try this:

```
(IN\s+)\((.*?)\)
```

(replace matches with `$1[$2]`)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ss4tVA/1

But generally don't use Regexes to parse SQL (fragments.) Consider using a full-blown parser.